# Opening PyGTK Python Module Error in py2exe

Tags: python, pygtk, subprocess, py2exe

I have a project written in Python 2.7 and PyGTK, with py2exe for compiling. I have two modules, "Launchpad.py" and "RegistrationScreen.py". I need to open RegistrationScreen.py from Launchpad.py.

I am using the following code currently:

```
def open_registration(event, data=None):
    subprocess.Popen(["python", "RegistrationScreen.py"])
```

This works fine when I test - the window is opened without the shell window opening.

However, when I compile using py2exe, I get the following log error on executing the created application.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Launchpad.py", line 26, in
>   open_registration   File "subprocess.pyc", line 672, in **init**
>   File "subprocess.pyc", line 882, in _execute_child WindowsError:
>   [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

How do I fix my code so py2exe will compile it correctly? Is there another way I can open the RegistrationScreen.py module's window from Launchpad.py, that won't throw errors in the final .exe file?

Comment: You might want to mention py2exe in the title or a tag.

Comment: I don't have a solution but a couple of things you can try. See if putting RegistrationScreen.py in the same directory as the exe created by py2exe helps. That is the exe runs without the error. If that does work, then in your setup.py script you will have to find some way of including RegistrationScreen.py as part of the package. Maybe - http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data ?

Comment: That didn't fix it...which is just as well, as RegistrationScreen.py is probably the single most source security critical module in my entire application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the path. RegistrationScreen.py is (probably) compressed inside dist/library.zip, but your code that calls it is looking for it in dist/RegestrationScreen.py.

I don't know what the best solution to this is... py2exe is kind of a pain for accessing files.

Also, you probably don't want to be doing `subprocess.Popen(["python", "RegistrationScreen.py"])` because you can't guarantee your users will have python installed and accessible systemwide. If you really need a separate process, then maybe you should run py2exe on RegistrationScreen.py individually to create a separate .exe, and then include that in the dist folder of your main .exe?

I know that's somewhat convoluted, but it would probably work. And as I said, there might be a better way.

Comment: raises a good point.  Why are you calling a Python script from a Python script/exe?  Why isn't the second script a Python module/class that is used more conventionally?

Comment: RegistrationScreen is supposed to be a sub screen of Launchpad...perhaps I should rethink it being a separate module at all. Thank you!